# How to change a Window Owner using its handle

Tags: winapi, window, owner

I want to make a .NET Form as a TopMost Form for another external App (not .NET related, pure Win32) so it stays above that Win32App, but not the rest of the apps running.

I Have the handle of the Win32App (provided by the Win32App itself), and I've tried [Win32 SetParent() function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633541(VS.85).aspx), via [P/Invoke in C#](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetParent.html), but then my .NET Form gets confined into the Win32App and that's not what I want.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you're looking for is to P/Invoke `SetWindowLongPtr(win32window, GWLP_HWNDPARENT, formhandle)`

[Google Search](http://www.google.com/search?q=setwindowlongptr+parent)

Comment: The problem is that I googled with the "change windows owner" word instead of searching for "change windows parent". :)

Comment: I passed by this answer several times thinking it was answering the wrong question, until I read the following in the msdn docs: ""You must not call SetWindowLong with the GWL_HWNDPARENT index to change the parent of a child window. Instead, use the SetParent function." This  statement is misleading. GWL_HWNDPARENT changes the OWNER, not the  parent, of a window. It is safe to use for that purpose. "

Answer (score 2):

Yes! 
I've already have a P/Invoke import of SetWindowLongPtr (which is x64 safe). And using Reflector I searched upon the Form.Owner property ( i.e. the get_Owner(Form value) method )
and managed to change the owner with

```
SetWindowLongPtr(childHdl, -8, OwnerHdl)
```

I was looking what the -8 (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF8) meant before I could post the solution here, but Joel has already pointed it out.

Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

It has now been 12 years since this question was asked so I thought I would provide an updated answer from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowlongptra).

> Do not call SetWindowLongPtr with the GWLP_HWNDPARENT index to change the parent of a child window. Instead, use the [SetParent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setparent) function.

Comment: Please read the question again. It is not about changing the **parent** of a child window. It is about changing the **owner** of another top level window. These are two completely different operations. As explained in the comment of the currently accepted answer, `SetWindowLongPtr(..., GWLP_HWNDPARENT, ...)` is the correct way to change the owner handle.