# How to place windows form on top of given window (known by handle) in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, window

I'm trying to overlay child window of some application with a form.
I have handle to that window so I successfully used `GetWindowRect()`
 to get coordinates and correctly place my winform on the screen.

However I have problem with order of application's windows and my winform.
With TopMost parameter set to true my form overlays menu drop lists of the main window of the application and generally doesn't look very elegant. With this paramter set to false, my form hides below all windows and is invisible.

Is it possible to place my winform above only one, specific window (to which I have the handle) and maintain order of all other windows (keep it below them)?

To illustrate it. Now I have this order of visibillity(?):

1. My form (on top)
2. Application main window
3. Application child window

I want:

1. Application main window
2. My form
3. Application child window

Please keep in mind, that this another application is 3rd part product. Everything I have is the handle to the window which I want to overlay.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133122/how-to-change-a-window-owner-using-its-handle

Comment: I uncorrectly defined my problem, so I was searching in vain.
Sorry for a duplicate and thanks for help!